# Selenium IDE not detecting the id

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to run a test recorded using selenium IDE.  The following html is generated by the IDE

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=span.blt-txt</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=pt1:svMenu:np1:6:cni1::disclosureAnchor</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=pt1:r5:0:mr1:gts1:gts_pc1:itFilterFieldValue::content</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=pt1:r5:0:mr1:gts1:gts_pc1:cil1::icon</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=pt1:r5:0:mr1:gts1:gts_pc1:tt1:0::di</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=pt1:r5:0:mr1:gts1:gts_pc1:tt1:1:astTreeSNo</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=pt1:r1:0:rAstDtl:0:cb4</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id('pt1:ptGeneric:ot1::_afrTtxt')/x:div/x:h1</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

When I run the test/execute command I get an error saying  `[error] Element id=pt1:r5:0:mr1:gts1:gts_pc1:tt1:0::di not found`

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: and is that id actually on the page when the test runs? Those IDs give me hint that new release might broke some ID...

Comment: Hi Pavel, yes the id is very much there on the page where test runs, this is the first time I have written this test.                             The firepath shows the following xpath   .//*[@id='pt1:r1:0:rAstTbl:0:mr1:gts1:gts_pc1:tt1:0::di']

Answer (score 0):

1. the id seems to be generated try not to use this id or use contain
   (try to use other xpath)
2. i would use only the last word of the id (you need to check it)
   3.you can highlight to see where you are

example for contain 
./li[contains(.,'Model')]]

Answer (score 0):

Using generated ID in a testcase is usually a bad idea. When the server restarts / data change, these IDs tend to change, too.

Anyway, your problem seems to be the classical problem with timing. Are your elements AJAX-loaded when something is clicked / after a page change? If yes, Selenium tries to click them before they get fully loaded. You should use [`waitForElementPresent`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#storeElementPresent) before you click on the element that causes trouble.

Generally, using Selenium IDE for AJAX-heavy pages uses to get hard very easily. Consider switching to manual Selenium RC writing or, even better, Selenium WebDriver. You can have the best of both worlds - first click through your test in IDE, then export your code to WebDriver in any language, make required changes, add waits (implicit are often enough), you're done.